# Unable to fire jQuery change() event on selectlist from WatiN

Tags: jquery, watin

I have a select box

```
 <select id="myselectbox">
   <option value='a'>First option</option>
   <option value='b'>Second option</option>
 </select>
```

And jquery

```
 $('#myselectbox').change(function() {
    ...
 });
```

And a WatiN test

```
 SelectList list = Browser.SelectList(Find.ById("myselectbox"));
 list.Select("First option");
```

In IE, this changes the select box, but doesn't fire the jquery event handler. I am aware of the many issues surrounding the change() event handler in IE. So I have tried adding a number of things to the test to force the event to fire:

```
 list.Blur();
 list.Keypress('\r');
 list.Click();
```

I also tried to click outside the select box to remove the focus, hoping this would fire the event.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1: Just ran into the same problem myself

Comment: +1 : me too. Has anybody reported this as a bug yet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could manually fire the event:

```
$('#myselectbox').change();
```

The other JavaScript events you're firing don't change the value, so they won't fire the `change` event.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing this from Watin: Browser.Eval("$('#myselectbox').change();")  and that did the trick!

Answer (score 15):

Going off of Matt Ball's answer and the OP's additional steps, I added the following extension method to a test helper class.

```
using WatiN.Core;

namespace Some.Test.Project
{
    public static class WatiNExtensions
    {
        public static void ForceChange(this Element e)
        {
            e.DomContainer.Eval("$('#" + e.Id + "').change();");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, so far anyway, I've succeeded in doing:

```
SelectList list = Browser.SelectList(Find.ById("myselectbox"));
list.Select("First option");
list.ForceChange();
```

OK, it's a minor convenience at best, but I'm finding it useful. Anyway, upvotes from me for the OP and the answer!

Answer (score 7):

Using the JQuery ID Selector can create problems when there are two elements on a page with the same ID. The following code should drill down to the exact corresponding WaitN element

```
Element.DomContainer.Eval(String.Format("$({0}).change();", Element.GetJavascriptElementReference()));
```

Comment: But then again, you shouldn't have 2 elements with the same ID on the same page, as that's against the HTML 4 and HTML 5 spec.

Comment: Just wanted to know how to do this using **JavaScript** alone when _jQuery_ is not there on the page? I found this one better.

Comment: This is very helpful if the select does not have an ID set for example.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. The other options, wouldn't even fire the event. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"change" is the event. "onchange" is the event handler. WatiN's Select() is buggy; it ultimately is firing "onchange" as if it was an event, which doesn't help the poster who wants the "change" event to fire.

Ultimately one has to use JavaScript/JQuery to fire the "change" event, as stated in the answer, to get around this bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in IE's fireEvent. WatiN's SelectList.Select() generates something similar to

```
var newEvt = document.createEventObject();
newEvt.button = 1;
watin3.fireEvent('onchange', newEvt);
```

Where watin3 is the native HTMLSelectElement. The fireEvent call does not fire jQuery attached events. You can repro it by manually calling `$('#id')[0].fireEvent('onchange');`

So your best bet is to manually fire the event like others suggested using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    public static void SelectByValueAndBlur(this SelectList selectList, string value)
    {
        selectList.Focus();
        selectList.SelectByValue(value);
        selectList.Blur();
    }
```

Comment: Had to do it this way because jQuery wasn't defined for some reason when trying the other ways given.