# Using Eval in watin

Tags: c#, watin

I've been getting error when trying to implement this

```
   ie.Eval("$(this).parent().removeClass("sortHelper");");
```

I was refering to this page :[fire jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712825/unable-to-fire-jquery-change-event-on-selectlist-from-watin)

and visual studio finds a syntax error.Is this the correct way for me to declare Eval?

Answer (score 3):

You can see from the syntax coloring on Stack Overflow that you are prematurely terminating the string. Change your quotes to this:

```
ie.Eval('$(this).parent().removeClass("sortHelper");');
```

See the difference?

Comment: yup i see the differences,thanks for pointing it out,clearly need to change my spectacles :P

Answer (score 0):

Switch the quotes from the previous answer (single quotes are for char):

> ie.Eval("$(this).parent().removeClass('sortHelper');");