# How to fire a JQuery selector from WatiN

Tags: c#, jquery, watin

I am using watin to test a web page. The vast majority of which works fine. But I have a function that is run using JQuery. When the option of a SelectList is changed. When I run the browser and I have a break point in the js code the following jquery selector is fired.

$("#OwningRegion").change(function () {

But I cannot cause this to happen with watin. I have tried the FireEvent("change"). I have tried FireEvent("onClick"). I have tried .Option[1].Click(). etc.

Comment: I found my own answer. In StackOverflow .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712825/unable-to-fire-jquery-change-event-on-selectlist-from-watin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
browser.Eval(string.Format("$('#{0},.{0}').change();", id)); //Both for classes and id's
```

Comment: I used this Browser.Eval("$('#myselectbox').change();");

Answer (score 1):

jQuery-style selector support is now built-in to [WaTiN 2.0](http://watin.org/documentation/release-2-0-50-11579/):

> A new method Find.BySelector is added. It accepts any valid
>   jQuery/Sizzle CSS selector string. The following scenarios are
>   supported:
>
> ```
> var element = browser.Element(Find.BySelector(…));
> var div = browser.Div(Find.BySelector(…));
> var elements = browser.Elements.Filter(Find.BySelector(…));
> var buttons = browser.Buttons.Filter(Find.BySelector(…));
> ```