# Select from WatiN not updating knockout viewModel

Tags: c#, javascript, watin, knockout.js

I'm selecting a select input using the following code

```
WebBrowser.Current.Div(Find.ByClass("grideditrow"))
    .SelectList("lst" + itemName).SelectByValue(value);
```

Though selections are made correctly by WatiN, KnockoutJS viewModel binded to this input does not get updated with selected value. Is there anything else in WatiN to make sure selection are completed in Browser?

Comment: Try the solution from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712825/unable-to-fire-jquery-change-event-on-selectlist-from-watin

Comment: See this post answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877193/how-to-fire-a-jquery-selector-from-watin/7887209#7887209

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger change element by jquery, this updates the knockout model:

`browser.Eval("$('.grideditrow').val(value);$('.grideditrow').trigger('change');");`