# WatiN ClickNoWait equivalent for Blur method on TextField

Tags: watin

I have some editing that happens on in the `onblur` event for a text input which creates a pop-up if the field value does not fit the constraint. I know, archaic, but it exists, therefore it must be tested. I test other pop-ups that are created by button clicks using the `ClickNoWait` method but there does not seem to be a comparable `NoWait` event that will work with `Blur`. I tried `KeyPressNoWait` using (char)9 but no luck (the `onblur` event doesn't get fired). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing the java script code to fire a blur?

```
Browser.Eval("$j--.blur()");
```

See also:
[Unable to fire jQuery change() event on selectlist from WatiN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712825/unable-to-fire-jquery-change-event-on-selectlist-from-watin)

And:
http://api.jquery.com/blur/